# Override Spring Cloud Config values with environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

Is there a way to override properties set via a Spring Cloud Config Server with another property source (specifically, the system environment)? I know I could manually do it by looping through the `Environment` object's `PropertySource`s, but if I could set it up so that the `bootstrapConfig` source was lowest priority, that would be ideal.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this without writing your own Application Listener?

Comment: No, there's no other way to do it, at least not in Spring Boot 1.2.x. I haven't checked for 1.3.x (Spring Cloud Brixton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I accomplished this by writing a custom `ApplicationListener` whose Event fired early in the cycle, but after the Config Service's `PropertySource` was loaded. I've attached the code here in case anyone is interested. If there's an "official" Spring way to do this, I'm still interested, but this works:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.CompositePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ConfigServicePropertyDeprioritizer
        implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent>
{
    private static final String CONFIG_SOURCE = "bootstrap";

    private static final String PRIORITY_SOURCE = "systemEnvironment";

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationPreparedEvent event)
    {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getApplicationContext()
                .getEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
        PropertySource<?> bootstrap = findSourceToMove(sources);

        if (bootstrap != null)
        {
            sources.addAfter(PRIORITY_SOURCE, bootstrap);
        }
    }

    private PropertySource<?> findSourceToMove(MutablePropertySources sources)
    {
        boolean foundPrioritySource = false;

        for (PropertySource<?> source : sources)
        {
            if (PRIORITY_SOURCE.equals(source.getName()))
            {
                foundPrioritySource = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (CONFIG_SOURCE.equals(source.getName()))
            {
                // during bootstrapping, the "bootstrap" PropertySource
                // is a simple MapPropertySource, which we don't want to
                // use, as it's eventually removed. The real values will 
                // be in a CompositePropertySource
                if (source instanceof CompositePropertySource)
                {
                    return foundPrioritySource ? null : source;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```