# Modify Spring Cloud Config precedence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

How do you lower the precedence for Spring Cloud Config's property loader? I need to be able to override the properties via command line arguments, but that's currently not possible due to the Cloud Config property loader being highest precedence.

For example, if MyApp.jar is pulling the variable "foo=bar" from MyApp.yml in Cloud Config, I would like to be able to use this command:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar --foo=baz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently override the precedence. But you can do something like this (in `myapp.yml` for example):

```
foo: ${fooOveride:bar}
```

Then you can do `java -jar MyApp.jar --fooOveride=baz` and then `foo=baz`.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't be feasible with hundreds of properties. I may have to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551039/override-spring-cloud-config-values-with-environment Thanks for the info though!

Comment: What's your use case in changing hundreds of properties? Why not use `myapp-myprofile.yml` in config server?

Comment: We need the ability to override any arbitrary property when responding to outages and other "call-in" type situations. (For example, the developer may need to reduce or increase the number of database connections.) Because of the way our process works, changing the Git repo would requiring calling in multiple people in the middle of the night to peer review, accept the PR, etc. It would be preferable to be able to override the property in the client and then perform the fix once people are available to review the changes.

Comment: It's also useful for things like testing, where you want to override a single property and don't want to have to commit the changes (or maintain a local Cloud Config server with a local copy of the repository).

Comment: You can also post to `/env` to test individual properties and using `/bus/env` send them to multiple instances with spring cloud bus.

Comment: Hrm. Didn't know that one. Good to know!